# asp rendercontrol errors out when there is a link in a column

Tags: asp.net

i am tring to convert a reapeter to an xls file but i keep getting a an error 
when my repeater includes a linkbutton.
hereis the error 
Control 'Repeater1_ctl00_ctl00' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

how can i remove the link befor in use rendercontrol

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=finance.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

        Repeater1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write("<table>");
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.Write("</table>");
        Response.End();
        //.Replace("</?(a|A).*?>", "")
    }
```

here is the link that causes the issue
updated: here is the full repeater

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                <tr class="odd">
                                                    <td class="  sorting_1">
                                                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>' OnClick="OnClickCust" > <%#Eval("Customer")%></asp:LinkButton></td>
                                                    <td class=" "><%#Eval("YearMakeModel")%></td>
                                                    <td class=" "><%#Eval("Coverage")%></td>
                                                    <td class=" "><%#Eval("TermMiles")%></td>
                                                    <td class=" "><%#Eval("CustomerCost")%></td>
                                                    <td class=" "><%#Eval("Dt")%></td>

                                                    <td><%#Eval("SalesPerson") %></td>
                                                    <td><%#Eval("dealStatus")%></td>
                                                    <td><%#Eval("vchCampaignID")%></td>
                                                    <td><%#Eval("contractNo") %></td>
                                                </tr>
                                         </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: post your source code of ASPX file

Comment: i dont see why you need the rest of the code but i have update to show the full repeater